# instanceof does not work for extracting child class from a list of parent class objects in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following three classes:
Parent

```
class Parent{
  public String title;
  public Parent(){}
  public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
  }
  public String getTitle(){
    return this.title;
  }
}
```

Child 1

```
class Child1 extends Parent{
  public String c1title;
  public Child1(){}
  public void setC1title(String title){
    this.c1title = title;
  }
  public String getC1itle(){
    return this.c1title;
  }
}
```

Child 2

```
class Child2 extends Parent{
  public String c2title;
  public Child2(){}
  public void setC2title(String title){
    this.c2title = title;
  }
  public String getC2itle(){
    return this.c2title;
  }
}
```

I stored the instances of child classes in an ArrayList <Parent> list and uploaded the ArrayList to the RealtimeDatabase. I can successfully retrieve the ArrayList, however this piece of code fails to work as intended for the ArrayList retrieved from Firebase but works for the local ArrayList:

```
for(Parent p : list){  //list is the ArrayList<Parent> obtained from Firebase
  if(p instanceof Child1){
    Log.d("Activity1", "1st child");
  }
  if(p instanceof Child2){
    Log.d("Activity1", "2nd child");
  }
  else{
  Log.d("Activity1", "No match found");
  }
}
```

I am unable to understand the reason behind it. Does the locally stored ArrayList has some additional information about the stored objects which gets lost when stored in the Firebase? What should be the ideal workaround for filtering out the child objects?

Edit: Code to retrieve ArrayList from Firebase

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test");
        mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Parent>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Parent>>() {};
                ArrayList<Parent> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
                List<Parent> list = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully obtained the test list");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: can post the code that retrieve  the date from firebase

Comment: it seems what you're getting is normal because you use `Parent` class

Comment: However when I use the same ArrayList <Parent> which I created locally, the filtering works. Could you please explain as to why the local ArrayList works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the data from the database you're using this:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Parent>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Parent>>() {};
ArrayList<Parent> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
List<Parent> list = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);
```

In this code you're telling Firebase to read a `Parent` instance from the snapshot, so that's precisely what it does.

If you want it to read the specific child that you wrote into the database, you will have to do two things:

1. Write information on the type of class to the database.
2. Ask Firebase for an instance of that specific class when reading from the database.

So when writing, this could be something like:

```
if (object instanceof "Child1") {
  ref.child("type").set("Child");
}...
```

And then when reading back, you'd read the data, loop over the results and instantiate the correct class based on the `type` property:

```
mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String type = child.getChild("type").getValue(String.class);
            if ("Child1".equals(type)) {
                Child1 child1 = child.getValue(Child1.class);
            }...
        }
    }
```

I don't think there's any way to do this on an entire list of children with a single API call.